# How to test React with hooks and PubSub-js with Jest Enzyme

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-hooks, enzyme, publish-subscribe

hello I have a simple app that connects with a topic and then updating he's state, seems to be working when playing around, but I have a problem with how to properly write a test for it
There is a library I using https://www.npmjs.com/package/pubsub-js

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import PubSub from 'pubsub-js'

const App = () => {

 const [data, setData] = useState([])

 const mySub = (msg, pubData) => {
  setData(pubData)
 }

 useEffect(() => {
  const token = PubSub.subscribe('TOPIC', mySub);

  return () => {
   PubSub.unsubscribe(token)
  };
 },[]);

 return (
  <input onChange={() => {}} value={data && data[0]?.value}
 )
};
```

```js
import React from 'react'
import PubSub from 'pubsub-js'
import { mount } from 'enzyme'
import App from '.'

const mocked = [{ value: 1}]
describe('should receive some date', () => {
 it('xx', () => {
  const app = mount(<App />)
  PubSub.publish('TOPIC', mocked);
  PubSub.publishSync('TOPIC', mocked);
  // WHAT NEXT?
 })
})
```

I've tried some
spies, finding input and checking values, but nothing change... why?
How should I test this Function component?

Comment: Where does `mount` function come from?

Comment: @slideshowp2 I added imports

Answer (score 0):

Since the `PubSub.publishSync()` operation will trigger `mySub` event handler that updates the state of the component. Make sure you wrap the code that causes React state updates into [act()](https://reactjs.org/docs/test-utils.html#act), otherwise, you will get a warning:

> Warning: An update to App inside a test was not wrapped in act(...).

E.g.

`index.jsx`:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import PubSub from 'pubsub-js';

export const App = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState('a');

  const mySub = (msg, pubData) => {
    setData(pubData);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const token = PubSub.subscribe('TOPIC', mySub);

    return () => {
      PubSub.unsubscribe(token);
    };
  }, []);

  return <div>{data}</div>;
};
```

`index.test.jsx`:

```
import React from 'react';
import PubSub from 'pubsub-js';
import { mount } from 'enzyme';
import { App } from './';
import { act } from 'react-dom/test-utils';

describe('67422968', () => {
  it('should receive data and update the state', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(<App />);
    expect(wrapper.text()).toBe('a');
    act(() => {
      PubSub.publishSync('TOPIC', 'b');
    });
    expect(wrapper.text()).toBe('b');
  });
});
```

test result:

```
 PASS  examples/67422968/index.test.tsx (7.254 s)
  67422968
    ✓ should receive data and update the state (28 ms)

-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File       | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files  |   91.67 |      100 |      75 |   90.91 |                   
 index.tsx |   91.67 |      100 |      75 |   90.91 | 15                
-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        7.902 s, estimated 8 s
```

package versions:

```json
"enzyme": "^3.11.0",
"enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.15.5",
"react": "^16.14.0",
"react-dom": "^16.14.0",
"pubsub-js": "^1.9.3"
```

Comment: unfortunately not updating state for me...
I have empty array as starting state, and its not changing at all,